# SQL JOINS: Why does Sqlite3 JOIN USING gives a correct answer but JOIN ON does not?

Tags: sqlite, join

I'm expecting to see *Sally Smith* listed with CityName equal to 'Kansas City' which I do get when using `JOIN USING` but I don't get when using `JOIN ON`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```sql
sqlite> select Customer.*, City.* from Customer inner join City USING(CityId);

CustomerId  CityId      CustomerName  CityId      CityName   
----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  -----------
1           1           Bob Smith     1           Kansas City
2           1           Sally Smith   1           Kansas City
3           2           Tom Smith     2           New York   
5           2           Bob McKenner  2           New York   

sqlite> select Customer.*, City.* from Customer inner join City on Customer.CustomerId=City.CityId;

CustomerId  CityId      CustomerName  CityId      CityName   
----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  -----------
1           1           Bob Smith     1           Kansas City
2           1           Sally Smith   2           New York   
3           2           Tom Smith     3           Houston    

sqlite> select * from Customer;

CustomerId  CityId      CustomerName
----------  ----------  ------------
1           1           Bob Smith   
2           1           Sally Smith 
3           2           Tom Smith   
4                       Mary Smith  
5           2           Bob McKenner  

sqlite> select * from City;

CityId      CityName   
----------  -----------
1           Kansas City
2           New York   
3           Houston    
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are joining on the wrong columns:

```
select Customer.*, City.* from Customer inner join City 
on Customer.CustomerId=City.CityId;
```

change it to:

```
select Customer.*, City.* from Customer inner join City
on Customer.CityId=City.CityId;
```

Comment: Fine if it is solved and don't forget to accept the answer.